# Swipe to refresh on ScrollView

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to do something like facebook, when we drag the scroll view until a negative y, the activity indicator will show up and refresh the view.

When i implement the following code, it is working on IOS. However, when run on Android devices, the scroll y seem only possible to have 0 or more than 0 value and cannot scroll be scroll to the negative area.

```
async void ContentScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
    if (!hold)
    {
        if (ContentScrollView.ScrollY < -70)
        {
            hold = true;
            scrollLoadingBar.IsRunning = true;
            scrollLoadingBar.IsVisible = true;

            netStructure structure = await Net.getWebServicesData("chart.asmx/GetCampaignChart?username=" + App.username + "&password=" + App.password + "&campid=" + App.campid + "&noOfChart=1&callback=");
            if (structure.status)
            {
                App.chart1 = structure.returnObject;
                setcampaignchart();
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Loading Chart Error", structure.errorMessage, "Ok");
            }

            scrollLoadingBar.IsVisible = false;
            scrollLoadingBar.IsRunning = false;
        }
    }
    if (hold)
    {
        if (ContentScrollView.ScrollY == 0)
        {
            hold = false;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get this to work on Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update as on 09/09/2020: As @johan-franzén has commented, `RefreshView` should be used. [Here is the official documentation on how to use RefreshView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/refreshview)

I'm guessing you want a Xamarin.Forms solution even though you haven't mentioned so in your question, because of the Xamarin.Forms tag. You needn't code that by hand. James Montemagno has done all the hard work for us. Here is the link to [PullToRefreshLayout](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-PullToRefreshLayout) github page. You just need to add PullToRefreshLayout at the place of ScrollView in Xaml and set the ScrollView as it's Content.

Edit : Explaining usage as suggested by @cheesebaron .

You can install the plugin Nuget package [Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh/) .

Then we can implement PullToRefresh action by Adding **PullToRefreshLayout** as parent to the ScrollView. I am quoting the example given in Github page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
x:Class="RefreshSample.Views.ScrollViewXamlPage"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh;assembly=Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh"
Title="Xaml Scroll">
<controls:PullToRefreshLayout
      IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
      RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
      IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}"
      RefreshColor="Blue"> 
      <ScrollView
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Purple"/>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Maroon"/>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Purple"/>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Maroon"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ScrollView>
  </controls:PullToRefreshLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Please add more description with usage of this library. As the answer stands it is very low quality and does not really conform to StackOverflow quality

Comment: @RyanShine Right-Click on Packages folder > Add Packages .  Add Packages window will pop-up. Search Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh . Library will apear in the left portion. Select that and then click on Add Packages. Now library will be added to your project and then you can refer the widget in Xaml code as explained in the example

Comment: the thing is what is SetBinding? i just get confuse there

Comment: After reload success, layout does not move up, always progress bar showing. Anyone faced this?

Comment: PullToRefreshLayout is now deprecated and you can use Xamarin Forms RefreshView

Comment: @JohanFranzén I have updated the answer as per your suggestion. Thanks